# How to generate generic class at runtime in Java?

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a class

```
myClass<T>
```

I also have a Type, totally unrelated to the class.

How do I generate a myClass where the generic parameter T is of my type in java reflect?

I tried

```
myClass.class.getConstructor()
```

But I can't get any further than that. Where can I specific the generic parameters to be given to the constructor?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Generics are not passed to the constructor, eg: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`. It's a compile time check.

Comment: Generic types don't exist at runtime. You'll have to create the corresponding raw type.

Comment: See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As generics are a compile time check, they doesn't have much meaning at runtime.  In reflections you can use the non-generic types.

```
 MyClass<T> myClass = /* MyClass.class */.newInstance(); // gets a warning but works.
```

Comment: well if it were like this then you would just do `MyClass<T> myClass = new MyClass<T>();`

Comment: I am assuming that `MyClass.class` is not known at compile time or there is some reason to use reflections